# Writing html to a page

Tags: asp.net, html, razor

I am writing some text to a page which contains some html.  I write it like this

@text

But the html appears as text like this

some text.  some more text.

What I'd like to happen is for the html to be rendered not as text but as actual html.  So in this example, I'd like a link to appear.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `Html.Raw` method which will not HTML encode the output contrary to the `@` operator:

```
@Html.Raw(text)
```

Warning: be careful with this because your site now becomes vulnerable to XSS attacks. You should do this only if you have total control over the `text` variable. If this variable comes directly from an user input, or a query string parameter or a form field, you might get into trouble. If you want to sanitize the user input so that it is safe to be used with the `Html.Raw` helper you could use the [AntiXss](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) library.

Comment: "user input" or from a querystring varible!